# Access variable name in lambda function

Tags: android, reflection, kotlin

I'm trying to access the name of a variable inside an iterator

```
listOf(someClassVariable, anotherClassVariable, yetAnotherClassVariable).forEach {
    if (it.foo()) {
        map.add(it, ::it.name)
    }
}
```

but getting `unsupported [references to variables aren't supported yet]` error at `::it.name`. Any ideas/workarounds?

Comment: do you just want to return the value of `it.name`? or do you actually want something like a supplier or similar that will return the name, when you access the supplier? (something like a lazy evaluation?)

Comment: Hi @Roland I want the name of the variable, not a property called "name". So for the first case it would be `map.add(someClassVariable, "someClassVariable")`

Comment: ah ok... now I got you... interesting... this doesn't seem to work yet, even though `::someClassVariable.name` would... what are you trying to accomplish that way? maybe there is another approach too... I mean: now you manually put all the variables into the list... if that becomes more dynamic maybe also the rest will solve itself more easily? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it vice-versa, i.e. having a list of references to your class variables and iterate over them and then get the actual value by calling invoke on it:

```
listOf(::someClassVariable, ::anotherClassVariable, ::yetAnotherClassVariable).forEach { varRef ->
    val varValue = varRef() // assignment optional... you can also just do it the way you want ;-)
    if (varValue.foo())
        map.add(varValue, varRef.name)
}
```

Comment: Nice approach ;-) Thanks!